# C++ 3D array declaration using vector

Tags: c++, arrays, 3d

I have some C++ code where I am declaring 2D arrays using "vector" with the following method:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> Array2D(X, std::vector<double>Y);
```

where X and Y are the dimensions of the array.

This works beautifully for what I need to achieve.
However I would like to look at using the same method for 3D, XYZ arrays.
I assume I start with:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>
```

but how do I declare the dimensions, ie Array3D(X, ?????)

Comment: Would you mind posting a [MCVE] please.

Comment: DON'T use such nested vectors to create 3D matrices. They are slow, since the memory is not guaranteed to be contiguous anymore and you'll get cache misses. Better use a flat vector and map from 3D to 1D and viceversa.

Comment: @vsoftco how to use a flat vector and map from 3D to 1D?

Comment: @Ahmetİnal (X,Y,Z) -> (X + Y * DX + Z * DY * DX), where DX and DY are the dimensions on X and Y, respectively

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is *fill* vector constructor, which constructs a container with n elements, and each element is a copy of value provided.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> Array3D(X, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(Y, std::vector<double>(Z)));
```

will create X by Y by Z vector. You probably would like to use `typedef` for this type.

Comment: Legend. Spot On. That is exactly what I was after. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can declare like

```
 std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > > Array3D(X, std::vector<std::vector<double> >(Y, std::vector<double>(Z)));
```

Where X, Y, Z are the dimension of 3D vector.

**NB**

It's better not to use 3D vector as mentioned by [vsoftco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093378/vsoftco)

> DON'T use such nested vectors to create 3D matrices. They are slow, since the memory is not guaranteed to be contiguous anymore and you'll get cache misses. Better use a flat vector and map from 3D to 1D and viceversa.